# How users can sign up with null values in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

some users can resgister with null values in my cakephp website !! 
when i try to register with null value im getting the error messages of my model, but someone do that, i found 8 users with no data (no usernam, no email, no names... !!!!! )
this is my signup (add) action:

```
if($this->request->is('Post')){
        $this->User->create();
        $this->request->data['User']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->User('id');
        if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
            $iduser=$id=$this->User->getLastInsertId();
            $this->Session->setFlash(_('your accoutn has been created, check you inbox.'));
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'login',$iduser));
        }
        else
            $this->Session->setFlash(_('Erreur !'));
    }
    $this->set('title_for_layout','users sign up');
```

and this is a part of my users model :

```
public $validate =array(
    'username' => array(
        'length' => array(
            'rule'      => array('minLength', 5),
            'message'   => 'error !',
            'required'  => true,
        ),
        'alphanum' => array(
            'rule'      => 'alphanumeric',
            'message'   => 'error !',
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule'      => 'isUnique',
            'message'   => 'error !)',
        ),
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'length' => array(
            'rule'      => array('minLength', 6),
            'message'   => 'error !',
            'required'  => true,
            'on'        => 'create'
        ),
        'alphanum' => array(
            'rule'      => 'alphanumeric',
            'message'   => 'error !',
            'on'        => 'create'
        ),

    ),
    'email' => array(
        'email' => array(
            'rule'      => 'email',
            'message'   => 'error !',
        ),
        'unique' => array(
            'rule'      => 'isUnique',
            'message'   => 'error !',
        ),
    ),
```

(other fields are checked too)

so, how someone can signup with no data  ??????!
please help !

Answer (score 0):

Are the creating the accounts and then removing the data thereafter?

Is there the facility for the user to edit these details out later on?
You need to specify which fields are empty and post the full validation from the controller.

Comment: 1 question : no, i dont think that !! because the stat of account is 0 (account with stat 0 cant login in normale case , and stat cant change by non-admin user)
2 question: like i tell you the users stat is 0 (so they cant logib, and edit thier details)
the big problem is the usernames is also clear (with no data) so how th user can login !! (and users cant change thier usernames !!!  so the problem is in the registration action i think !)